# User friendly way to access an MTP device (Android 3.0 tablet)

Tags: android, tablet, mtp

Is there a user friendly way to access a MTP device from Ubuntu such as an Android 3.0 tablet?

Thanks.

Comment: Just Plug it as a storage device.. nautilus will prompt you with what you want to do.

Comment: @Uri, that... didn't happen.

Comment: I'm not sure how is it on Honeycomb, but on Gingerbread on settings>application>development>usb debugging i have ticked the box and whenever i  connect my phone to my pc a notification appears on the phone.

Comment: @UriHerrera: Gingerbread does not use MTP, it uses USB mass storage.

Comment: duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/87667/getting-mtp-to-work-with-a-galaxy-nexus  and http://askubuntu.com/questions/308293/connect-galaxy-nexus-to-ubuntu and many more best solution today is updated GVFS with MTP support

Answer (score 3):

One suggestion is to use Ubuntu One or DropBox to move stuff on/off.

Ubuntu's default music management application, Rhythmbox (Applications → Sound & Video → Rhythmbox Music Player), supports first to fifth generation iPods, including the iPod mini, iPod Photo, iPod Shuffle, iPod nano, and iPod Video. Rhythmbox can transfer music to these iPods and create playlists.

I think your answer can be found here in the 10.04 manual:

[Portable music players](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/musicvideophotos/C/music-portable.html)

Answer (score 1):

I did this, open a terminal, copy these commands in sequence and run them:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
exit
```

Nautilus can then successfully mount and copy files. I noted that opening files from the device still has permissions issues but after copying them to the PC all is fine (which is what I wanted to do anyway).

Tested on Samsung Galaxy III and Sony Ericsson Experia J (both Android 4.1.2).

Answer (score 1):

I have had issue with almost all MTP filesystem utilities apart from jmtpfs.

See here,

http://research.jacquette.com/jmtpfs-exchanging-files-between-android-devices-and-linux/

Really easy to use, just do

`mtp detect`
`jmtpfs <mountpoint>`
Boom, done

and to unmount
`fusermount -u <mountpoint name>`

Hope this helps