# Getting MTP enabled devices to work with Ubuntu?

Tags: mtp

> Since **Ubuntu 13.04** storage access to external devices via **MTP** is supposed to **work out of the box** via a GVFS-MTP module.
>
> While this question is about the Galaxy Nexus, other Android devices as well as **Windows Phones** and MTP enabled media players **are also supported**.
>
> For **troubleshooting** see [this anwser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87667/getting-mtp-enabled-devices-to-work-with-ubuntu/308366#308366).

---

I am having quite a bit of problems getting file-transfers working over MTP with the Galaxy Nexus. I am using Kubuntu 11.10 64-bit, and this is what I have done and the results I get:

1. Added rule for device in `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`. The rule is the following and works for `adb`:

   ```
   SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6860", MODE="0666", OWNER="leob" #Galaxy Nexus
   ```
2. Restarted `udev` (and computer just to make sure).

Adb works, and all methods for reading from the device via MTP seems to work (I have tried mounting with mtpfs, gmtp and using the mtp-tools package directly). When I try to write to the device however, nothing I have tried works.

As an example, running `mtp-newfolder test_dir 0 0` gives the following output:

```
libmtp version: 1.1.0
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung GT-P7510/Galaxy Tab 10.1.
Folder creation failed.
ERROR: Could not close session!
```

If I run `mtp-folders` after a failed mtp-newfolder without re-plugging the device, I get the following output:

```
Attempting to connect device(s)
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung GT-P7510/Galaxy Tab 10.1.
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
mtp-folders: Successfully connected
Friendly name: (NULL)
Error 1: Get Storage information failed.
Error 2: PTP Layer error 02fe: get_all_metadata_fast(): could not get proplist of all    objects.
Error 2: (Look this up in ptp.h for an explanation.)
Error 2: PTP Layer error 02fe: get_handles_recursively(): could not get object handles.
Error 2: (Look this up in ptp.h for an explanation.)
LIBMTP_Get_Storage()
: Resource temporarily unavailable
OK.
```

Accompanied by the following in dmesg:

```
[ 1000.912082] usb 2-4: reset high speed USB device number 7 using ehci_hcd
[ 1001.045877] usb 2-4: usbfs: process 3166 (mtp-folders) did not claim interface 0 before use
```

Does anyone have any idea about what to do?

**EDIT:**

I also tried the PTP mode. Again, reading works fine, but I cannot write anything to the device.

Comment: I don't think it's Samsung.... and I think it is Android. My Honeycomb powered device is the exact same way where you have to use MTP only. I think this is how all post 2.3 Android devices are going to be.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Since Ubuntu 13.04, storage access to external devices via MTP works out of the box via a GVFS-MTP module.**

Related question: [Are there any plans to improve mtp support on future Ubuntu releases?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247943/are-there-any-plans-to-improve-mtp-support-on-future-ubuntu-releases)

For troubleshooting, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87667/getting-mtp-to-work-with-a-galaxy-nexus/308366#308366).

---

For me, it was a problem of not having the latest `libmtp` files on my system. So I fixed the problem and made [this write-up to help others](http://www.humans-enabled.com/2011/12/how-to-fix-samsung-galaxy-nexus-mtp.html).

**Summary of the link:** There was a bug in the `libmtp` bundled with older Ubuntu releases. This bug was already fixed in the [latest source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmtp/files/libmtp/) of `libmtp`.

Comment: The issue seems to be fixed in packages for Ubuntu 12.04, so those can be used if you are brave enough to do it. I grabbed them from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libmtp/1.1.1-1 and created the packages for system (and the same for gmtp)

Comment: @Shannon. Thanks. This is the best solution. Wish I had found it first.

Comment: rhythmbox still freezes and gives errors (LIBMTP_Send_Representative_Sample(): could not get object info.) when trying to access the nexus, and nautilus gives: Unable to mount Galaxy Nexus; Error initializing camera: -60: Could not lock the device. Poo.

Comment: It would be nice to update instructions to get latest mtp, not 1.1.1

Answer (score 25):

Have you tried [Bilal Akhtar's](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/author/bilalakhtar/) suggestion at [omgubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-connect-your-android-ice-cream-sandwich-phone-to-ubuntu-for-file-access/)?

### Connecting your Android phone or tablet to Ubuntu with MTPFS

1. **Setup**

   First up, install the necessary tools with `sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs`

   Connect your Galaxy Nexus to your computer. On your phone, open up the notification drawer, and click on "USB Connection type". Make sure that MTP is selected.

   [image: image showing Android USB connection settings]

   Then, run these commands:

   ```
   mtp-detect | grep idVendor
   mtp-detect | grep idProduct
   ```

   You shall get an output like this:
   [image]

   Now, run these commands:

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
   ```

   A Gedit window should open up. Type this text in it, all in a **single line**:

   ```
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="VENDORID", ATTR{idProduct}=="PRODUCTID", MODE="0666"
   ```

   Replace `VENDORID` with the `idVendor` you had noted down earlier. Similarly, replace `PRODUCTID` with the `idProduct` you had noted down. In my case, they were `04e8` and `685c` respectively, but they might have been different for you.

   Save and close the file. Then, **disconnect** your phone and run these commands:

   ```
   sudo service udev restart
   sudo mkdir /media/GalaxyNexus
   sudo chmod a+rwx /media/GalaxyNexus
   sudo adduser $USER fuse
   ```

   `$USER` is a default shell variable and should be the user you want to add (usually yourself). Now, run this command:

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/fuse.conf
   ```

   In the Gedit window, remove the `#` at the beginning of the last line (the one that begins with `#user_allow_other`) like this:

   [image]

   You're almost done! Now, restart your computer, and then run these three commands:

   ```
   echo "alias android-connect=\"mtpfs -o allow_other /media/GalaxyNexus\"" >> ~/.bashrc
   echo "alias android-disconnect=\"fusermount -u /media/GalaxyNexus\"" >> ~/.bashrc
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```
2. **Usage**

   Connect your phone, make sure your phone is using MTP and run `android-connect`.

   Voila! You can now browse your Android phone contents using Nautilus. Just fire up the file manager, and then in the side bar click GalaxyNexus to browse your phone contents just like you would do with a USB stick. You can also add, remove and modify files just like a normal file system.

   [image: screenshot of nautilus displaying phone contents]

   To safely remove the phone, just run `android-disconnect`.
3. **Conclusion**

   From now onward, you just need to run `android-connect` to mount your phone and then `android-disconnect` to safely remove your phone. Everything else should be handled automatically. I tried many ways of getting the mount and unmount to happen automatically on cable connect, but this was the best solution I could come up with.

   These two commands **won't require root permissions** to run. All users who are members of the fuse user group should be able to run these commands without root access.

   That's it! You've successfully connected your Ice Cream Sandwich phone to your Ubuntu computer. The process may be long for a newbie, but I’m sure someone will come around and make a GUI for all of this so that everything happens smoothly. :)

Comment: Yes, already tried most ways of using the mtpfs-tools. As Shannon found out, it was apparantly a bug in libmtp.

Comment: It works, but I have some questions. 1. What does that udev configuration do, why doesn't it work without it? 2. By what magic does it know which device to mount when you do `mtpfs`, or does it simply support only 1 connected device at a time?

Comment: Also when copying a large file (with Nautilus) it will appear to copy very fast (50MB/s) but during that time it doesn't copy anything. Only when the progress bar hits 100% it will start the real copy (and the interface hangs). Maybe some kind of buffer option can be disabled?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the answers you want. I'm sorry.

Comment: Did all of this, but getting this message when trying to android-connect:
fusermount: failed to open /etc/fuse.conf: Permission denied

fusermount: option allow_other only allowed if 'user_allow_other' is set in /etc/fuse.conf
even though I edited /etc/fuse.conf as instructed.

Comment: package is not anymore available on ubuntu apt-get

Answer (score 24):

## Connecting devices via MTP with GVFS

Since Ubuntu 13.04 storage access to MTP capable devices works out of the box through a [GVFS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gvfs) backend. Please have a look at *[Are there any plans to improve mtp support on future Ubuntu releases?](https://askubuntu.com/q/247943/40581)* for installation instructions prior to 13.04.

This solution should work for **all Android devices** providing MTP functionality and probably all non-Android devices with MTP functionality like **Windows Phones** and **Portable Media Players**.

### Don't be confused

There has been some confusion, let's try to clear things up:

- You **don't** need to do anything that may void your warranty!
- You don't need to root your device.
- You don't need to unlock the bootloader. (You can find instructions for Android her[e](https://source.android.com/source/building-devices.html#unlocking-the-bootloader).)

Unlocking just refers to the operating systems lockscreen in this answer.

- You don't need to configure developer access to your device like ADB, fastboot or something similar through certain udev rules. (You can find instructions for Android in chapter *Configuring USB Access* [here](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html#setting-up-a-linux-build-environment) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/213874/40581).)
- As far as I know, you also don't need FUSE or configure FUSE-related options.

### Troubleshooting issues

1. **I cannot put files onto the device.**

   Your device must be **unlocked** to access the storage of the device with Ubuntu via MTP.

   [image: showing device in nautilus in locked and unlocked state]
2. **I'm getting an error message that the device cannot be mounted.**

   If you get the below error message, try to replug the device *once*.

   [image: error message that might pop up when connecting]

   If the error message appears again open a new nautilus window from the launcher (preferable by clicking the icon of the device) and probably closing the current nautilus window. Possibly related: [How create a udev rules to disable one of Android devices?](https://askubuntu.com/q/668164/40581)
3. **Check if there are udev rules for your device**

   Open a terminal and type `lsusb`. Find your device in the output and note down the ID (e.g. `0fce:01b1`). The first part is the vendor ID the last part the product ID.

   Open the corresponding mtp udev rules file with `nano /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules` and seach for your product ID (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>). If you can't find it, you have to create a custom entry in `/etc/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules` following the pattern below and **reboot**.

   ```
   # SONY Xperia Z2 MTP
   ATTR{idVendor}=="01b1", ATTR{idProduct}=="01b1", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
   ```

   You should consider **filing a bug** against the [libmtp package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libmtp) (more precisely [libmtp-common](https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/trusty/all/libmtp-common/filelist)) to have your device included in future versions, if this worked for you.
4. **I still can't connect**

   Your device is either not supported by the underlying `libmtp` or you might experience the same issue I have with my Lumia 620, please follow the workaround (steps to reproduce) I posted in [LP#1247572: Nokia Lumia 620 (WP8) fails to mount reliably via gvfs-mtp in nautilus](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gvfs/+bug/1247572). (The device still doesn't work flawless here, but using `mtp-detect` helps.)

   You should search the [libmtp bug tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/libmtp/bugs/) for your device and follow the instructions for new devices on [the project page](https://libmtp.sourceforge.net/) to open a bug report.
5. **The bug tracker lists my device as supported but it still won't work**

   In some cases a bug report concerning your device might have already been filed and solved in a more recent libmtp release than what your distribution ships with (e.g.: [Motorola Moto G](http://sourceforge.net/p/libmtp/bugs/934/)). If that's the case you will either have to wait for the official repositories to get updated or go looking for an updated PPA.

   An updated list of all libmtp versions available through the official Ubuntu software channels and private PPAs may be found [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libmtp) (make sure to expand *Other versions of 'libmtp' in untrusted archives*). As of 2014/02/13 [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ematttbe/+archive/ppa) by Matthieu Baerts offers the latest libmtp package available for Ubuntu.

   **Warning**: this PPA contains a variety of different and possibly unstable packages. I would advise against adding it to your system. Instead, you could download the libmtp packages separately and manually install them on your system.

   Please familiarize yourself with [PPAs and their risks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) before moving any further. Please also read the paragraph below on restoring your original packages before proceeding with the following steps:

   1. Head to the [package detail page of the PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ematttbe/+archive/ppa/+packages) and expand the libmtp entry
   2. Download the following packages: `libmtp-common`, `libmtp-runtime`, `libmtp9`, `mtp-tools`. Make sure to choose the right architecture for your system (this will generally be `amd64`).

      Here are the package links as of 2014/02/13: [libmtp-common](https://launchpad.net/%7Ematttbe/+archive/ppa/+files/libmtp-common_1.1.6-21-1a2669c6-1%7Ematttbe0_all.deb), [libmtp-runtime](https://launchpad.net/%7Ematttbe/+archive/ppa/+files/libmtp-runtime_1.1.6-21-1a2669c6-1%7Ematttbe0_amd64.deb), [libmtp9](https://launchpad.net/%7Ematttbe/+archive/ppa/+files/libmtp9_1.1.6-21-1a2669c6-1%7Ematttbe0_amd64.deb), [mtp-tools](https://launchpad.net/%7Ematttbe/+archive/ppa/+files/mtp-tools_1.1.6-21-1a2669c6-1%7Ematttbe0_amd64.deb)
   3. Proceed to manually install the updated packages with dpkg (change `$HOME/Downloads` to your download folder and make sure no other deb files are present:

      cd "$HOME/Downloads"
      sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   4. Once everything has been installed successfully, restart your computer, unlock your Android device, connect it via USB and it should show up in your file manager.

   This has worked fine for me (@Glutanimate) with my Motorola Moto G. Because I was running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I first had to install an updated version of `gnome-gvfs`. Please see *installation instructions prior to 13.04* at the top for more information.

   To undo the changes if something goes wrong or if the device still isn't recognized you will have to manually install the original packages. Head to the [libmtp source overview](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libmtp) and find your Ubuntu release. Expand the entry in question and proceed to download the packages, just like you did in step 2 before. Continue with the installation as described in step 3 and reboot your system. Everything should be back to normal now.

Comment: +1 for 'Don't be confused'

Does not work for my galaxy s3 mini though :(

Comment: Worked for my Samsung Galaxy tablet with Android 4.1.2, but I cannot edit the files on the go. Do you have a solution for that too?

Comment: _"Some guides suggest adding udev rules to a file called 51-android.rules. These are not for MTP,..."_

You lost all credibility when you said that. The rules in udev/rules.d/ are entirely flexible. 51-android-rules is a perfectly appropriate place for them. You might just as reasonably put the rule in 52-phone-rules

Comment: @Auspex The line could have been written better, but instead of complaining you could have done that (that would require reading and understanding the entire post) or provide a better answer. Looking at your profile I assume you know how SE sites are supposed to work. How you (mis-)manage your files in `/etc` is entirely up to you. As explained above, ideally all udev rules should be provided ootb. If not, one should file a bug to include the missing rule in `/lib/.../69-libmtp.rules`, so everyone will be happy with the next release.

Comment: I _do_ understand how SE sites are supposed to work. But YOU are the one who suggested creating a special file for MTP devices, and I maintain that it is not only unnecessary, it's not right: the phone should STILL be in the 51-android-rules file if it were provided ootb.

Comment: @Auspex I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here. I repeat: how you manage your files in `/etc` is up to you. `/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules` is what the package maintainers chose and I am suggesting to file a bug against that package (I have updated my answer) for the users who encounter this issue. If you still have a problem with that, kindly talk to the maintainers or post your own answer. I am now bowing out of this conversation with you on this topic.

Comment: +1 for opening new Nautilus windows (I'm using Windows Phone, connect to Ubuntu 14.04.5).

Comment: your suggestion 3) worked great for connecting my Honor 8X5G to Debian 11 - KDE. Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

All programs based on `libmtp` still seem to have issues with the Galaxy Nexus (as of libmtp 1.1.3). Programs based on `gphoto2` work for me.

Personally I'm using `gphotofs`, available in a package of the same name.

Use `gphotofs ~/mymountpoint` to mount, then `fusermount -u ~/mymountpoint` to unmount when you're done.

Comment: Just upgraded to 12.04 and it seems that libmtp 1.1.3 is not working correctly like you said. Will have to investigate this a bit more. gphotofs is working perfectly though so thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Using `gphotofs` leaves me with a single directory that is empty.

Answer (score 4):

Install the following and reboot:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install android-tools-adb gvfs-backends go-mtpfs jmtpfs gmtp  libgoogle-glog0v5 libmtp-common libmtp-dbg libmtp-dev libmtp-runtime libmtp9 gmtp jmtpfs mtp-tools python-pymtp
```

Comment: And yes, this answer applies also to _"Ubuntu 13.04 [and above; where] storage access to external devices via MTP is supposed to work out of the box via a GVFS-MTP module"_. Because it may just not be installed out of the box. Even when your MTP device is somehow automounted already! (But giving you read-only access or other problems.)

Comment: @tanius I must say that MTP is so painfully slow that I don't even use it anymore. esfile explorer has an ftp server and I just use curl to upload files to the device on my local network.

Comment: This command points to the source of the problem:
```The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gvfs-backends : Depends: gvfs (= 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.2) but 1:1.20.3-4salbabix27trusty is to be installed
                 Depends: gvfs-daemons (= 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.2)
                 Depends: gvfs-libs (= 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.2) but 1:1.20.3-4salbabix27trusty is to be installed
                 Depends: gvfs-common (= 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.2) but 1:1.20.3-4salbabix27trusty is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: You should note that when this fails as in above comment, remove and reinstall "ubuntu-desktop" and the above with sudo apt-get install --reinstall. and then restart.

Comment: I have updated the package list for at least 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, I would install `jmtpfs` (`sudo apt-get install jmtpfs` in terminal - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> ), then create a folder with `mkdir foldername` and then mount the device with `jmtpfs foldername`, then go to nautilus (Files).

If your device is not compatible with the `libmtp` version in ubuntu. 
You have to download and build a recent `libmtp` (> 1.1.12), as in: 
[How can I install the latest version of libmtp?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118478/how-can-i-install-the-latest-version-of-libmtp)

You should be able to see the folders also using `mtp-folders` in a terminal or with the graphic interface `gmtp`.

Previous steps could show an error if you run them without `sudo`:

```
libusb_open() failed!: Permission denied
```

To avoid using sudo you should add your device to the `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` file as above (see desgua) and reloading rules or restarting.

Answer (score -1):

Just a small workaround, connect your ICS based phone with good old MASS STORAGE http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1556367

```
adb install UMS1.0.apk
```

Comment: Whilst this is a good solution for some phones, this only works if a phone has a seperate sd-card. In relation to the original question this wouldn't work with the Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: Even with a separate sd-card, I don't think mounting as a mass storage device is an option on newer versions of Android. Although, "there's always a back door somewhere" so I won't go so far as to say it's not possible.

Comment: That was 4 years ago ;)