# How can I install the latest version of libmtp?

Tags: android, compiling, mtp

In the latest version of the libmtp library there are fixes for my Android device so I would like to install the latest version I'm just not sure how! I would assume that this would pushed into the official repositories at some point, so the smart advice would probably be just to wait, but I would like to know how to do this myself if anyone could tell me.

I'm currently using Ubuntu 12.04 and am running libmtp-1.1.2, the latest version (libmtp-1.1.3) has recently been released and the tar.gz file is downloadable from this direct link: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libmtp/libmtp/1.1.3/libmtp-1.1.3.tar.gz

How do I install this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you need to get the file, extract the tarball and change to the folder. You can do this from a terminal:

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libmtp/libmtp/1.1.3/libmtp-1.1.3.tar.gz
tar zxf libmtp-1.1.3.tar.gz
cd libmtp-1.1.3
```

Second, build the source and install the binaries:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

I'd be more inclined to use *checkinstall* - so not use the make install command, if so enter this commands instead:

```
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```

---

If you have not complied any software you might need some extra packages prior to starting.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall wget
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall

Comment: `gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`.
how do I solve this issue?

Comment: I've just used this solution to upgrade libmtp from 1.1.6 to 1.1.12. I had doubts if it would work without uninstalling the old version (which would basically mean uninstalling the whole system as lots of stuff depends on this library). It actually worked without uninstalling anything.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the ppa mentioned here will also allow you to update your libmtp:

[How To Properly Mount Android 4.0+ Devices In Ubuntu Using Go-mtpfs ~ Web Upd8: Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-mount-android-40-ubuntu-go-mtpfs.html)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install go-mtpfs
```

Optional, custom Unity Launcher for Go-mtpfs:

```
sudo apt-get install go-mtpfs-unity
```

But be careful: This PPA has other packages that you may not want to install.

Comment: note to others: libmtp hasn't been maintained in this PPA since 2013