# Can't mount an Vodaphone Smart 4 Turbo as storage device

Tags: android, mtp

I have a 4.4.4 android phone (Vodafone Smart 4 Turbo), and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on my laptop. If I try to connect my phone via usb cable to manage my files, I can't, the pc doesn't respond. But if I connect it as PTP I can manage my pictures. How do I solve this problem? Can somebody help me?

Comment: You should include your dmesg logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of your issue is the version of the MTP library available in Ubuntu 14.04LTS - [v1.1.6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libmtp&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) - does not recognise our phone (Vodafone Smart Turbo - model 890N).

The workaround I found was to recompile libmtp from the latest [upstream sources](http://libmtp.sourceforge.net/) which also includes all the latest bugfixes which resolves the your observed issues.

We do have a [question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118478/how-can-i-install-the-latest-version-of-libmtp) that covers this.

I took that answer and created my own PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/libmtp
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

[source](https://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2015/02/16/what-do-you-do-when-your-android-phone-is-not-recognised-by-ubuntu/) is my blog

To revert this use ppa-purge to remove the PPA and downgrade the libmtp version back to the trusty version:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:fossfreedom/libmtp
```