# Are there any plans to improve mtp support on future Ubuntu releases?

Tags: mtp

Even when I did manage to connect my Google Nexus to Ubuntu, I think it would be great to have mtp support right from the start.

Comment: I just installed Ubuntu 13.04. I'm pretty glad to say that I now have full MTP Support for my Nexus 7. It works pretty well so far.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yep, here's the fix you're looking for:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/903422

This is fixed in 13.04.

---

As of Jan 28th

> Upgrade Gvfs in Ubuntu 12.10 and 12.04 to get Android 4.0 support for devices which don't support USB Mass Storage interface

1. Add the PPA to your system

   ```
   sudo ppa-purge ppa:webupd8team/gvfs-libmtp
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Then, launch Software Updater (previously known as Update Manager) and install the available updates.
3. Once everything has been updated successfully, restart your computer, unlock your Android device, connect it via USB and it should show up in your file manager.

---

Please refer to [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) if you have questions about anything related to a Personal Package Archives (PPA) and refer to the source on [OMG Ubuntu](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/upgrade-to-gvfs-with-mtp-support-in.html) (it has some comments worth reading).

Comment: This **Launchpad** bug is about the limitation in **MTP** support for 'Samsung' brand devices. *This may also need effort from Samsung, providing a fix to firmware for (all/most of) their 'mobile' devices.*

Comment: PPA for 12.10 and 12.04 can be found here: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/upgrade-to-gvfs-with-mtp-support-in.html  (Upgrade Gvfs in Ubuntu 12.10 and 12.04 to get Android 4.0 support for devices which don't support USB Mass Storage interface)

Comment: @Rinzwind that's useful, put it in the answer not in a comment!

Comment: But but but you are scary :=) (hopes Jorge is drinking coffee when he reads this)

Comment: This does *not work* with 13.10 (yet?)

Comment: does not work with 14.04 either

Comment: You probably don't need this PPA for 14.04.

Comment: Right. Just improved mtp support for 14.04 if we need mtp at all. We do already have numerous protocols for transferring data without loss. Granted I haven't read the MTP specifications. There may be something golden in there.

Answer (score 1):

What is perhaps needed to for someone to develop **OpenMTP**, initially for **Ubuntu** desktop, 'mobile' **Ubuntu**, and for **Android**.

There are too many specials in the design, including *Microsoft DRM*, that are documented in the 'development kit' for devices. This needs to be re-thought as a simpler, fully extensible design - that does not have **windows**, or **Windows Media Player**, as a architectural element (or pre-requisite).

*It should also support a single, headless storage repository on the host (eg. **Ubuntu**), and/or to the cloud, that both devices (attached) and apps (local) can interact with. This should support: **photos**, **audio/video media**, **e-books**, etc.*

---

from [wikipedia > Media Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol)

> The Media Transfer Protocol is described by Microsoft, who introduced it, as a protocol for intelligent storage devices based on and compatible with Picture Transfer Protocol (PTP). Whereas PTP was designed for downloading photographs from digital cameras, Media Transfer Protocol supports the transfer of music files on digital audio players and media files on portable media players, as well as personal information on personal digital assistants. MTP is a key part of WMDRM10-PD, a digital rights management (DRM) service for the Windows Media platform.
>
> Media Transfer Protocol (commonly referred to as MTP) is part of the "Windows Media" framework and thus closely related to Windows Media Player. Versions of the Microsoft Windows operating system from Windows XP SP2 support MTP. Windows XP requires Windows Media Player 10 or higher; later Windows versions have built-in support. Microsoft have also made available an MTP Porting Kit for older versions of Windows back to Windows 98. Apple Macintosh and Linux systems have software packages to support MTP.
>
> The USB Implementers Forum device working group standardized MTP as a fully fledged Universal Serial Bus (USB) device class in May 2008. Since then MTP is an official extension to PTP and shares the same class code.