# Mount a Win8 Phone as Share on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: usb, mount, phone

I'm trying to mount a Nokia 620 phone running Win8 on my Ubuntu 12.10 box. I can see the device using `lsusb`, but from what I can see it's not listed under `sudo blkid`. I'm trying to follow the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB

Has anyone done this successfully?

Just for clarity, I want to be able to copy files from my computer onto the phone.

I've tried using a Win8 image on Virtualbox - no luck. I have all USB devices enabled for the virtual machine.

Comment: I think, wp devices are like apple devices. You need Zune to do all that.

Comment: Windows Phone 8 mounts just as storage, no Zune required (on Win PC)

Comment: After upgrading to Raring and updating my phone with the latest updates from Nokia, this now mounts as a removable drive (including the removable storage) using MTP. You may need to install the MTP drivers as per Web-E's answer, but try both of these first.

Answer (score 3):

I don't own any wp devices. So this answer goes in kind of assumption and internet research. Anyone wants to correct any information, please do so.

Windows Phone 8 only Support MTP and has no Native Mass Storage Support. But you said, it is not even detected on Windows 8 , that is a bit confusing.

However, since Windows phone uses MTP, so only we need update the MTP library.

While searching on internet, I found out a blog that talks about it, and he can mount it. But on Mac . You can look [here](http://doitdifferent.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/connecting-a-lumia-920-or-other-wp8-device-to-a-maclinuxipad/)

So, for ubuntu, I would suggest to give a **try** to updated GVFS with MTP support. The article was written for Android 4.0+ devices which doesn't support Mass storage but only support MTP. You can have a look and instruction [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/upgrade-to-gvfs-with-mtp-support-in.html). They talk about updating the MTP library.

But, interesting thing is, they have added a note on Feb 13, 2013. with a [list of devices](http://ppa.webupd8.org/post/43022082410/libmtp-updated-for-ubuntu-quantal-and-precise-with) that are supported  in the unstable PPA.  And **Lumia 920** is there. So it might be possible, it will be working with 620. If not you have to wait.

So I would suggest,

- add ppa `ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp` & install all available update.
- Reboot, unlock your device and connect. See if it is now on Nautilus.
- If not, add this unstable ppa `ppa:webupd8team/unstable` & avail the updates. There should be one update, `libmtp`. Install, reboot and retry.
- The downgrade info is there on webup8 site. Remove `unstable` ppa first and then `gvfs-mtp`

Comment: No luck so far, but thank you for putting me onto MTP - I'm investigating this now.

Comment: I just received a Lumia 620 yesterday and had trouble to get it to work with 13.10 (the PPA hasn't been updated until now). I documented my troubleshooting in a bug report linked in my answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/87667/getting-mtp-enabled-devices-to-work-with-ubuntu/308366#308366

Answer (score 0):

My neighbor used this guide to do pretty much the same thing..... Hope it helps! [Nokia](http://metallicracquet.blogspot.com/2011/01/to-mount-nokia-phones-on-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Thank you for that. I've tried this - it gives me an empty Obex utility window. This is most likely wrong (or at least not quite what I want) since I know I have files on the storage of the phone.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.