# Unable to connect Galaxy Nexus to Ubuntu 12.04 through gMTP

Tags: 12.04, mtp

When I launch gMTP for browsing the files in Galaxy Nexus I get the following error message:

> Failed to get storage parameters from the device - need to disconnect.

I have already tried the answers given in the following question:

- [Getting MTP enabled devices to work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87667/getting-mtp-to-work-with-a-galaxy-nexus/88630#88630)

Comment: The Android MTP implementation is bad already, and on Samsung devices it's even worse (I have a Galaxy S3...). If you don't need MTP for a specific reason, I recommend, as a workaround, to set up an ssh server on your Ubuntu machine and then to use andftp or ES file explorer to connect to it via sftp over WLAN. The only tool that allowed me to connect to my phone on 12.04 was mtpfs, and that also only if the phone was in a good mood...

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to be able to browse files on your Android phone in 12.04, you can just use the suggested PPA in this good article

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/upgrade-to-gvfs-with-mtp-support-in.html

I personally find it slightly unstable compared to ubuntu 13.04's support, but may be I am nitpicking and overall it works just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable method for me has been to use go-mtpfs. It requires manual mounting/unmounting (via terminal - I did a little mini script to make it easier to remember).

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-mount-android-40-ubuntu-go-mtpfs.html

Also, since you are on a Galaxy Nexus, I do believe the latest cyanogen mod roms have the ability to mount as mass storage OR MTP/PTP. If you're rooted, it may be worth checking out as well.