# Android device not found

Tags: 14.04, android, mtp

i have a problem with one of my android devices which is suddenly not recognized anymore. It worked yesterday, but since of today the device won't be listed anymore in the explorer. The cable is fine since it is working with all other devices that used to work.

Actually i have no idea where to start to get it working again. How could it suddenly stop working? Btw. i haven't done any updates in the meantime neither to the device nor the Ubuntu machine which makes it even weirder...

I am on Ubuntu 14.04, device is a Samsung A3

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you selected "USB for MTP" on your phone? It also may help to reboot both devices. I've had similar issues on my Nexus 5.

Comment: Yes i did. I also changed it back and forth... will try rebooting.

Comment: Rebooted? If that doesn't work, see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/320561/cant-connect-to-android-device?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for your time... rebooting indeed did help :-/

Comment: You're very welcome :)