# Supress mouting errors

Tags: mount

I am attaching my phone via usb to my ubuntu box to charge it.

Unfortunately, every few seconds a popup appears with the following error:

```
Unable to open MTP device '[usb:003,009]'
```

I don't care if ubuntu is able to open the device or not, I just want to supress the error.

How can I do this?

Comment: I faced same issue with my Nokia Lumia. I bought a better data cable and now it connects/charges without those mounting error.

Comment: See if this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/320561/cant-connect-to-android-device

Comment: I think the best answer combines the actual answer below with the first comment by @ManishKumarBisht ... In a nutshell, you can and should select "charge only" in your (Android) phone, but a proper cable will also avoid the error message and allow data connection as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Android phone you can set the preferred USB connection type: for charging or for data access. Look somewhere in the USB options (depending on Android version and flavour). For iPhones I don't know.

[example for Android 6.0](https://www.addictivetips.com/android/how-to-set-the-default-usb-connection-type-in-android-6-0/)