# Ubuntu 13.04 unable to mount my lumia 720

Tags: mtp, nokia, windows-phone

I shifted permanently from the windows 8 to the Ubuntu, but I have a windows phone and I need to sync music pictures books. But in Ubuntu 13.04 I cannot mount the device and displays error.

[image]

Foremost I need to mount the device to perform any action.

Comment: Can you switch it to "usb storage" (or similar)?

Comment: The error message also appears with Android phones and the devices usually work when you replug them once in not locked state.

Comment: after an update to the linux image the phone is shown as an audio player inside it there's phone storage disk that contains the files but it doesn't allow me to copy anything from the pc to the disk

Comment: The answer to this question is shared in http://askubuntu.com/questions/87667/getting-mtp-enabled-devices-to-work-with-ubuntu/308366#308366,.

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling battery saving mode.