# Cannot see certain files on USB mounted device (MTP Android Xperia Play)

Tags: usb, files, transfer, mtp

I'm using an emulator for PS2 and I was going to transfer my `.iso` files from my Xperia Play to Ubuntu 12.04.

So I look for my `.iso`'s in the folder through file manager and it looks as it's empty, but there is a notification on the top asking to the open picture viewer, because there are pictures in this folder.

I cannot see or interact with anything and there are no files are hidden.

PS: To the forum mods: I am dyslexic and I find your requirement for exacting grammar and spelling unfair. It took a whole half hour just to get past your blocks.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. This is not a regular forum and while we have moderators, post reviews are also done by advanced users via a review interface that queues among others very short posts, low quality posts and posts from new users for review. Reviewers are encouraged improve lack of spelling and formatting and help new users. I'd say there is no more discrimination on stackexchange instances like AskUbuntu against certain users than in any other software.

Comment: @Reviewers Don't close with duplicate against some random MTP question, this question deserves a proper explanation or at least a comment why this is happening and its cause.

Answer (score 0):

The Xperia Play is a MTP capable device and should be mounted via MTP or PTP protocol. The notification you are getting indicates that your device might be mounted with the PTP protocol instead.

Depending on the version of Ubuntu you are using (older than 13.04) you might need to install an additional PPA, see the following question for instructions: [Getting MTP enabled devices to work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87667/getting-mtp-enabled-devices-to-work-with-ubuntu)

You will also need to switch to the MTP protocol on your device, which is also shown in one of the answers from the above question, as well as troubleshooting connection issues.