# How do I transfer large files from my phone to my computer?

Tags: android

I recently downloaded a 6.7 GB file onto my Samsung Galaxy S3. I want transfer it to my computer but I get this error: libmtp error:  Could not get file from device. This is the only time it has ever done it and it is getting annoying. I am also running Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: It is a BUG in libmtp. 13.04 is end of life so please upgrade to at least 13.10 and it will be fixed. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/87667/getting-mtp-enabled-devices-to-work-with-ubuntu

Comment: I'm having the same error on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version while copying few files of each of 15-16 MB from Moto X Play.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd rather connect via wi-fi you can try an app called Airdroid on the play store. After installing this app on your phone you just need to open a browser and go to the provided address. From then you can copy paste files and look everything almost like you were on your phone. And all of this is done wirelessly.

You can also use FTP if you have an FTP Server installed.

Hope I could help.