# MotoG not recognized in ubuntu 12.04, MTP mode not supported. Why?

Tags: 12.04, usb, android, mtp

I bought a MotoG handset and wanted to transfer music files to my phone. But as I connect it to my laptop, Ubuntu doesn't recognize the phone, whereas it detects my friend's HTC phone. Basically, when my phone is on MTP mode, it is not recognized but once I switch to PTP mode, ubuntu does show up the device.

I believe its a driver issue. But the problem is I don't know what to do. Its very tedious to copy files to my phone otherwise. 
I also installed virtual box and installed windows on it, but when i connect my device, it says no USB device connected.

Please suggest a solution. Thanking in advance.

Comment: Do you want to use data cable or any other way is OK?

Comment: any other way is OK no problem. I just want to transfer my songs to my phone

Comment: Ok then please wait for a few minutes.

Comment: Have you installed `mtp-tools` on ubuntu?

Comment: Please try following the steps outlined in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87667/getting-mtp-enabled-devices-to-work-with-ubuntu/308366#308366).

Comment: @Jobin Yes i have done the following:-

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: No, you need to do `sudo apt-get install mtp-tools`.

Comment: @Jobin OK Sir, doing it right away!

Comment: @Jobin It worked just so perfectly!! :) Thanx a lot,Sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download this software from Google Play.

   [image: Dami]
2. Download Filezilla from Ubuntu Software Centre.
3. Open the app.

   [image: SDC]
4. Click on the settings button below.
5. Click on "Connection Authentication".

   [image: CA]
6. Type in your preferred "Username" & "Password".

   [image: UP]
7. Click "Save".
8. Now, click on "Setup Wifi-Hotspot".

   [image: SWH]
9. Type in your preferred "Username" & "Password". Try to keep the "Username" & "Password" for both "Connection Authentication" & "Setup Wifi-Hotspot" same. Its easier that way but then again its completely your choice.

   [image: U&P]
10. Click on "Save".
11. Now, go back and click on "Start Service".

    [image: SS]
12. Turn on your Ubuntu Desktop.
13. Next, launch Filezilla.
14. Now, beside "Host:" type - 192.168.43.1.

    [image: H]
15. Next, type your Username & Password.

    [image: UandP]
16. Beside "Port:" type - 8888 and click "Quick Connect".

    [image: P]
17. You will be able to see your phone memory on the right side of the Filezilla Window.

    [image: PM]
18. And also you can see the successful connection message at the top.

    [image: SC]

Now, you can do whatever you want.

Hope this helps! Thank you for your patience!

Comment: This was a brilliant idea,Sir. It worked totally fine till the connection establishment. But when i click "upload" on the file that I wanna transfer, it gets disconnected abruptly in the middle of a transfer.

Comment: My problem is solved,Sir. But thanx a lot for this new technique! Din't know it could be done this way too! :D

Answer (score 0):

I came here to find a native solution. The answer is a workaround and a long-one. A shorter answer would be to install ['wifi transfer'](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer) or [airdroid](https://www.airdroid.com/). 
You can create a wifi-hotspot on your phone, connect your pc to it and start these services at one-click. Then you can browse the contents of phone via browser url. You can download from phone and upload to phone also. The only disadvantage is there is limit on file-size in free version of these apps.