# phone not recognized in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, phone

Samsung GT-E1200i not recognized in Ubuntu 12.o4 using usb cable and I can find the drivers any where how can I get drivers

Comment: Please connect your phone and run `lsusb` command in terminal. Then [edit] your question and post output there.

Comment: it only listed the usb ports and only showed the mouse and the keyboard were can iI get the drivers to get my phone to run with Ubuntu

Comment: Please post output of that command to your question. You do not need any drivers. Just copy text from terminal and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 50 rep yet, so I can't comment, but I wanted to say that i happen to have the same problem. lsusb shows the following output:

> noah@DellLaptop:~$ lsusb Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung
>   Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP) Bus 001 Device 002: ID 4971:cb01
>   SimpleTech SP-U25/120G Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux
>   Foundation 2.0 root hub Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux
>   Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux
>   Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux
>   Foundation 1.1 root hub noah@DellLaptop:~$

I am using Lubuntu 15.10, and PCManFM recognizes the device right away but I can't read or write to the device in MTP mode, and in PTP mode it isn't recognized at all. I haven't yet run a lsusb with the device in PTP mode.

My device is a Samsung Galaxy Lite (SGH-T399), from T-Mobile. I made sure the USB cable is OK, and it works fine on my Windows 10 box. Is there perhaps some sort of daemon that needs to be installed?

Comment: Suggestion: Read [this old post](http://askubuntu.com/q/87667/37165) that had asked on "Getting MTP enabled devices to work with Ubuntu?". If still cannot be solved, then you could post this as a [new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and quote a link to this question to show related post without solution or non-working solution.