# How create a udev rules to disable one of Android devices?

Tags: usb, android, udev

I have an HTC Android phone.

Every time I connect it to computer I get a message:

```
Android Phone: Could not open MTP device "[usb:002,003]"
```

The numbers may be different. But the phone connects correctly.

`usb-devices` output

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#= 28 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bb4 ProdID=0f91 Rev=02.33
S:  Manufacturer=HTC
S:  Product=Android Phone
S:  SerialNumber=FA41BWB00560
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=06(still) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbfs
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=00 Driver=(none)
```

`lsusb`

```
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 048d:1336 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. SD/MMC Cardreader
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bb4:0f91 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.) 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04b8:0898 Seiko Epson Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

`lsusb -t`

```
/:  Bus 07.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/3p, 12M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/3p, 12M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/3p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/3p, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Imaging, Driver=usbfs, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Printer, Driver=usblp, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
```

`udevadm info -q all -n /dev/bus/usb/002/004`

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-1
N: bus/usb/002/004
S: libmtp-2-1
E: BUSNUM=002
E: COLORD_DEVICE=1
E: COLORD_KIND=camera
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/libmtp-2-1
E: DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/002/004
E: DEVNUM=004
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-1
E: DEVTYPE=usb_device
E: DRIVER=usb
E: GPHOTO2_DRIVER=PTP
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=usb-pci-0000_00_13_2-usb-0_1
E: ID_GPHOTO2=1
E: ID_MEDIA_PLAYER=1
E: ID_MODEL=Android_Phone
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Android\x20Phone
E: ID_MODEL_ID=0f91
E: ID_MTP_DEVICE=1
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:13.2-usb-0:1
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_13_2-usb-0_1
E: ID_REVISION=0233
E: ID_SERIAL=HTC_Android_Phone_FA41BWB00560
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=FA41BWB00560
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:060101:ffff00:
E: ID_VENDOR=HTC
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=HTC
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.)
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0bb4
E: MAJOR=189
E: MINOR=131
E: PRODUCT=bb4/f91/233
E: SUBSYSTEM=usb
E: TAGS=:seat:uaccess:
E: TYPE=0/0/0
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=611981507
```

`dmesg`

```
[   40.632283] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[   40.765458] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bb4, idProduct=0f91
[   40.765469] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[   40.765475] usb 2-1: Product: Android Phone
[   40.765480] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: HTC
[   40.765485] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: FA41BWB00560
[   40.766646] usb-storage 2-1:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   40.767102] scsi host10: usb-storage 2-1:1.1
[   40.864690] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   41.613079] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[   41.746616] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bb4, idProduct=0f91
[   41.746626] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[   41.746633] usb 2-1: Product: Android Phone
[   41.746638] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: HTC
[   41.746643] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: FA41BWB00560
[  101.942087] usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
```

I also found that for a short period of time after the phone is connected a usb-storage device is declared

```
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=06(still) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbfs
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

Then it disconnects and class is changed to `ff`.

```
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=06(still) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbfs
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=00 Driver=(none)
```

Comment: Please do the following for me: 1) `lsusb` and find your device or your devices (Bus and Device). 2) Start the command `udevadm info -q all -n /dev/bus/usb/your_bus_id/your_device_id` and use Bus and Device. Add the output of the command in step 2 into your question.

Comment: Ok and the output of `lsusb` too, I need only the part of your Phone

Comment: I will add it, but you can see VID & PID in `usb-devices`. @A.B.

Comment: I did not see the first comment. Added that too.

Comment: I'm not sure that those are really two USB devices.

Comment: But you could try a `ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="FA41BWB00560"`.  In my understanding, the values for `E:` can be accessed via `ENV{…}`

Comment: `[usb:002,007]`  & phone: `[usb:002,004]`  are two separate devices. If you didn't reboot or change USB port between the two commands running. Could you confirm that @Pilot6 then post full `lsusb`

Comment: @Sneetsher You are correct. I am updating. It looks like there is some other device that could not be connected and does not appear in `lsusb`. But it is still in the phone.

Comment: @Pilot6 , try also `lsusb -t` to see all interfaces

Comment: @Sneetsher I added the output. It looks like this is a similar issue with virtual CD, but it can't connect for some reason.

Comment: Can you add the output of `udevadm info -q all -n /dev/bus/usb/002/002`? That should be the `|__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M` of `Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M` in the output of `lsusb -t`

Comment: @A.B. I added the output. But that looks like a card reader and is not related.

Comment: I'm confused. What is your phone in the output of `lsusb -t`?

Comment: @A.B. , `Android Phone: Could not open MTP device "[usb:002,003]"` should be `Android Phone: Could not open MTP device "[usb:002,004]"` and in `lsusb -t` the phone seems to be bus 2 dev 4 . It has 2 interfaces.

Comment: The problem is that after I reconnect the phone the numbers change. I will reboot, reconnect the phone and check the numbers.

Comment: Now it is all correct. It writes `Android Phone: Could not open MTP device "[usb:002,003]"`. But it can connect the phone @A.B.

Comment: Added `dmesg` too @Sneetsher

Comment: @Pilot6 , now it seems clear why this confusion. at `40.632283` phone connected as device 3 , at `40.864690` disconnected , then at `41.613079 ` reconnect again as dev 4.  So you get libmtp error for bus 2 dev 3 . but what remains and what we see later is just  bus 2 dev 4.  (dev 3 already gone)

Comment: Is it possible to fix it somehow? Maybe run some `sleep 5` as a script, to let the phone switch the device? I think it does something like with the CD, but ejects by itself.

Comment: @Pilot6 delay may not work as with respect to udev these are two separate devices. Each one has its own events line. libmtp is triggered for both.  mtp udev rules are based on vendor/product ids. There should be something different between the 2 mode. Try unplug it, run `udevadm monitor -u -p` in terminal, then plug it , wait till it ready. Ctrl+C to end monitoring. then post it to paste.ubuntu.com .

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12275134/ @Sneetsher

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28790/discussion-between-pilot6-and-sneetsher).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `dmesg` output, it is clear that the phone connected twice.

- [   40.632283] 1st connected as USB bus 2 dev 3
- [   40.864690] disconnected
- [   41.613079] 2nd connected as USB bus 2 dev 4

The problem is:

- Both phone connection modes are using same attributes `idVendor`/`idProduct`/`bcdDevice`.
- libmtp udev rules use only `idVendor`/`idProduct` to filter devices in addition to non-important/common attributes `ACTION!="add"`, `ENV{MAJOR}!="?*"` and  `SUBSYSTEM=="usb"`
- libmtp udev rules use `ATTR` (not `ATTRS`), it does target exactly this device node `/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-1`. So we can't use interfaces nodes details as they are children nodes to this one.

To get what going on, use `udevadm monitor`. To see just events without details.

1. Unplug the phone
2. Open terminal and run `udevadm monitor -u` , `-u` to show UDEV events only (for clean output)
3. Plug the phone and wait till things settle down
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop monitoring

To get details (Environment properties) use [`udevadm monitor -u -p`](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12275134/) instead and compare output at that node:

- `UDEV  [107.024195] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-1 (usb)`
- `UDEV  [107.998137] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-1 (usb)`

Notice the difference in `ID_USB_INTERFACES`

Another cleaner way, using a udev rule  to collect only what we need:

1. Add a rule to `/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules` just after `LABEL="libmtp_usb_rules"`:

   ```
   ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTR{idProduct}=="0f91", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'env >> /home/username/udev-phone-mtp_%E{SEQNUM}.log'"
   ```
2. Reload rules

   ```
   sudo udevadm control -R
   ```
3. Replug the phone once.
4. This rule should be triggered twice. Comparing output at that node:

   `diff udev-phone-mtp_*.log`

   should bring: (this is just the interesting portion)

   ```
   < ID_USB_INTERFACES=:060101:080650:
   ---
   > ID_USB_INTERFACES=:060101:ffff00:
   ```

Exactly what Pilot6 (OP) could catch it using `usb-devices` before it reconnected.

---

I suggest adding this rule to `/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules`, just after `LABEL="libmtp_usb_rules"`:

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTR{idProduct}=="0f91", ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACES}==":060101:080650:", GOTO="libmtp_rules_end"
```

Comment: This chat discussion  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28790/discussion-between-pilot6-and-sneetsher related to this . Reported that: First time it worked well
A second time after unplug there was an error then opened after a delay.

Comment: I do not see any errors now. But the delay is still there. It is up to a minute to get the device mounted. I get the error if I do not wait till it gets auto mounted and try to open it in nautilus.

Comment: But this does not seem related, because I commented out your line and the delay is still there. The phone appears in the launcher but it can't mount for some time.

Comment: The delay is not Ubuntu related. It is an Android bug. I plugged of the phone from one computer and connected to another. There is the same delay.

Comment: @Pilot6 ,  Updated answer, with an easy way to catch it. Is the other computer not a Linux one?

Comment: I do not have non-linux computers ;-) But I have plenty of linux. The problem is that after the phone is disconnected it can't connect again for a while. I do not think it is linux related.

Comment: It was really an Android problem with the delay. I reinstalled firmware for another reason and the delay disappeared.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case `ID_USB_INTERFACES` were always the same, so I had to skip entire VID/PID.

Comment: @gmk57, There is still a twisted workaround it even so because they usually appear in order. My hint here is to create script that creates a file (empty lock file) ignore the 1st interface but does not skip 2nd interface if it find our existing lock file, and delete the file. If you can test it and make new question and answer it will be  worth sharing. I can help also with the udev rule and answer if you luck knowledge, just make new question and share info following this answer posted above.

Comment: @user.dz, I probably won't bother with scripts, because I mostly access this specific device through ADB, which still works and allows to copy files too. So I'm fine with your solution, just without `ID_USB_INTERFACES` part. Anyway, thanks for your willingness to help! :)  
BTW, I [filed an issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/libmtp/bugs/1897/) to **libmtp**, maybe they can fix it in a more generic way.