# unable to mount Discovery Kids Camera

Tags: usb, mount, camera

Trying to mount an older Discovery Kids Camera to a laptop running 14.04. Device shows up in `lsusb`.

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b35f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 009: ID 0d98:1007 Mars Semiconductor Corp. Discovery Kids  Digital Camera
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Read other posts that suggest using `gvfs-mount`

```
~$ gvfs-mount gphoto2://[usb:005,009]
Error mounting location: Error initializing camera: -105: Unknown model
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Most likely, the older model of Discovery Kids Camera has only a USB cable for data transfer. Newer model seems to have Micro SD memory slot, which enables the user to transfer data via Micro SD memory card. I did a brief search and found nobody has successfully manage to connect this type of camera in Linux, yet.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It is the older model with no micro sd slot,  just usb cable. I tried adding an entry for the device using the idVendor and idProduct following the link here: (http://askubuntu.com/questions/87667/getting-mtp-enabled-devices-to-work-with-ubuntu), and I just get "Unable to mount MARS USBDISK No MTP devices found".