# Not able to browse Google Nexus7 Tablet contents in Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04

When connecting a Google Nexus 7 via USB cable, the drive of the tablet is showing up in the Ubuntu File Browser(Nautilus) but the file system doesn't shows up.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: The device needs to be unlocked (normal screen lock, not anything weird). [This question](http://askubuntu.com/q/87667/178596) may help (you need `libmtp` etc installed).