# Unable to copy files to Samsung MPS - libmtp error: Could not send object property list

Tags: files, mp3-player

I have Ubuntu 16 and am unable to copy files from my computer to my YP-UTJ Samsung MP3 player. This is the error message

> There was an error copying the file into [drive name]:
>
> libmtp error: Could not send object property list.

I have googled this error but have not yet found a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the following packages:

`sudo apt-get -y install libmtpserver-dev mtp-server`

This was a workaround I used when I was unable to transfer files to my phone.

Comment: Looks like I've already installed that: libmtpserver-dev is already the newest version (0.0.4+15.04.20150219-0ubuntu3~gcc5.1).
mtp-server is already the newest version (0.0.4+15.04.20150219-0ubuntu3~gcc5.1).

Comment: I guess this askubuntu link may help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/87667/getting-mtp-enabled-devices-to-work-with-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

This is the error I got when there wasn't enough room on my phone for the file I was trying to copy.  Maybe check the amount of space you have free on your device?  That's what worked for me.

Comment: I'm getting this error on my desktop, there is plenty of space there.