# How to download photos

Tags: downloads

How do i download photos from my lumia 535 windows 8.1 mobile phone, bear in mind i'm not very techie, so give way. I have tried a USB connection from my phone to the computer with no luck.
Many thanks.

Comment: You may find some useful troubleshooting steps here: [Getting MTP enabled devices to work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/a/308366/178692)

Comment: Another comment: make sure the phone is set to mtp and not mass storage