# GoPro 7 does not work via MTP in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: usb, 22.04, mtp

My GoPro 7 does not work via MTP on my Ubuntu 22.04:

```
Oct 19 17:05:50 sesta11 kernel: [  124.113398] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
Oct 19 17:05:50 sesta11 kernel: [  124.263827] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=2672, idProduct=0047, bcdDevice= 0.01
Oct 19 17:05:50 sesta11 kernel: [  124.263842] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Oct 19 17:05:50 sesta11 kernel: [  124.263849] usb 1-4: Product: HERO7
Oct 19 17:05:50 sesta11 kernel: [  124.263854] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: GoPro
Oct 19 17:05:50 sesta11 kernel: [  124.263858] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: C3281325820830
Oct 19 17:05:50 sesta11 gvfsd[4988]: Device 0 (VID=2672 and PID=0047) is a GoPro HERO7 Black.
Oct 19 17:05:55 sesta11 gvfsd[5033]: PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
Oct 19 17:05:55 sesta11 gvfsd[5033]: LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
Oct 19 17:05:55 sesta11 kernel: [  129.718277] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
Oct 19 17:05:56 sesta11 gvfsd[5033]: inep: usb_get_endpoint_status(): Kein passendes Gerät gefunden
Oct 19 17:05:56 sesta11 gvfsd[5033]: outep: usb_get_endpoint_status(): Kein passendes Gerät gefunden
Oct 19 17:05:56 sesta11 kernel: [  130.479208] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 18
Oct 19 17:05:56 sesta11 gvfsd[5033]: libusb_open() failed!: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Oct 19 17:05:56 sesta11 gvfsd[5033]: LIBMTP PANIC: Could not init USB on second attempt
```

```
nsk@sesta11:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
nsk@sesta11:~$
```

Tried this, without success:
https://askubuntu.com/a/684128/40569

The system was upgraded from 20.04 and also older versions before (don't know exactly where it started).

I did not found out, what file was not found as it is indicated in the second last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It worked on a different USB port!**

- Though I restarted multiple times before
- Though I used the same cable
- It even is connected additionally to an usb extension cable now
- But it is connected now to the back side of the system!

---

**Additional info:**

it is working on the back side on the only USB 3.1 port, but not on all the other USB 3.0 ports.